# How to set RAILS_ENV to staging in a heroku review app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So right now in a Rails 5 heroku review app, RAILS_ENV is set to "production" in the config vars section. If I change the value to "staging" and try to run *rails console* on the heroku review app, it crashes with an error output of:

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

* development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:498:in `raise_no_secret_key': Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer: (RuntimeError)

      config.secret_key = 'xxx'

    Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.1.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:226:in `devise_for'
        from /app/config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `instance_exec'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:389:in `eval_block'
        from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:371:in `draw'
        from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Does setting the RAILS_ENV to "staging" mean I have to create a *config/staging.rb* file because Rails will infer environmental settings from there?

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, 3 things were needed:

I had to set *RAILS_ENV* to *staging* in the Heroku config vars section on the heroku review app. I created a config/environments/staging.rb file which was a copy of config/environments/development.rb. I also had to add generate a secret key using *bundle exec rake secret* and copy and paste that value into config/secrets.yml under a nested yaml key of

```
staging:
  secret_key_base: 12345xxy
```